# Can I mix PCIe cards version 2.0 and version 3.0 in motherboard adjacent slots?

Tags: ssd, motherboard, pci-express

Motherboard specification for expansion slot is :

> Slot5 : PCI-E GEN3 x8 Slot(EE : x8/x4 with Slot6)
>
> Slot6 : PCI-E GEN3 x8 Slot(EE : x0/x4 with Slot5)

CPU is E5-1620v2, PCIe lanes are coming from the CPU not the chipset.

I want to install :

- Slot 5 : Intel® SSD 750 Series requiring PCIe NVMe 3.0 x4
- Slot 6 : Intel® Ethernet Server Adapter I350-T4 requiring PCIe v2.1 5 GT/s, x4 Lane

Will the SSD get PCIe version 3 speed or will both slots set to PCIe version 2 because they are sharing 8 lanes ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Barring any bugs in the implementation, the PCI-E lanes are independent and each will negotiate the correct connection speed.

The switching between "one x8 slot" or "two x4 slots" doesn't break this.

Comment: I know that each port of 4 lanes can negotiate independent PCIe 3.0 speed but do the same port can negotiate independent PCIe version. There is an encoding scheme modification between v2.0 and v3.0.

From Intel  data sheet :
The PCI Express* port(s) are fully-compliant to the PCI Express* Base Specification, Revision 3.0 (PCIe 3.0)
Support for PCI Express* 3.0 (8.0 GT/s), 2.0 (5.0 GT/s), and 1.0 (2.5 GT/s)
Up to 40 lanes of PCI Express* interconnect for general purpose PCI Express* devices at PCIe* 3.0 speeds that are configurable for up to 10 independent ports"

Answer (score 0):

What motherboard are you using?

You shouldn't be facing bottlenecks with the speeds as the PCIe lanes work independently, as Philip explained.

Simple example would be usages of GPUs with other expansion cards while no bottlenecks are observed.